# Quartz not installing for Windows 8 Metro App Project

Tags: .net, windows-8, quartz.net

I have a problem with Quartz .Net library. I have made a research for best C# job scheduler and found out that Quartz is the best option. However, I cannot make it work with Windows 8 project. I am using Visual Studio 2012. The error I get from nuget is as follow:

```
> PM> Install-Package Quartz
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Common.Logging (≥ 2.1.2)'.
Installing 'Common.Logging 2.1.2'.
Successfully installed 'Common.Logging 2.1.2'.
Installing 'Quartz 2.1.2'.
Successfully installed 'Quartz 2.1.2'.
Adding 'Common.Logging 2.1.2' to Wonky Project.
Uninstalling 'Common.Logging 2.1.2'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Common.Logging 2.1.2'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Common.Logging 2.1.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly 
references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Quartz
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I have to add that I have tried to load manually missing library but still no luck. I have also tried to add quartz to library project and that actually worked, but then I couldn't reference the project library in Windows 8 App project. Visual Studio says then: "Unable to add reference to project Scheduler". Scheduler is a project library with Quartz installed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the version like  "Install-Package Quartz -Version 2.1.2"

Comment: Thanks, Ill give it a try tonight. However, I would like to mention that nuGet tried to install the exact version you say.

Comment: Use the version number as mentioned -- Version 2.1.2, Please let me know the status.

Comment: I have used that version - look at my logs above, still the same error.

Comment: Is this windows 8 project?